# Modifying Install options by User when installing msi

Tags: wpf, installshield-le

InstallShield LE provides us the option to either update the previous version(this keeping data) or remove the previous version completely and then install the new version. What I want is I want the user to choose whether they want to upgrade or completely install the new version. I am using InstallShield LE free version.

I am guessing I'll have to write some Install Script (feature provided by InstallShieldprofessional ). If this is the only option, then I just want to be sure before Iproceed to buy professional version

Comment: Have you tried Advanced Installer? http://www.advancedinstaller.com/

Comment: Yeah, But the problem is I guess I'll have to write custom actions and dialogs and how to call those custom actions while installer is running and I have no idea how to do that in Advanced Installer or InstallShield. I have browsed a lot and I've been doing that for past 1 week.

Comment: Not sure if this helps http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-c-sharp-ca.html Just a rough search gives me this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and upgrade to the Professional version for the very same reason.
Basically this kind of option needs to be design by adding feature into your install workflow.

This white paper help me to do it: http://resources.flexerasoftware.com/web/pdf/WhitePaper-IS-Designing-Update-Friendly-MSI-Installation.pdf

So yes, I would say that Professional version is the only option IF YOU WANT TO KEEP INSTALLSHIELD.
There are some other alternatives depending on what you try to achieve as describe here: http://dim-i.net/2011/02/01/5-reasons-installshield-limited-edition-sucks/

Hope it helps!

Comment: I would love to go with any alternative you suggest,if you have resolved this issue previously. Thanks in advance

Comment: I personally use the Professional edition to create custom feature in the deployment

Comment: But how to achieve this functionality,  surfing on the net only yielded me that I should create custom dialogs and custom actions, but I couldn't figure out how to do that. Please excuse me for my short knowledge in this ,I'm a newbie in this